# Vue2 - Vue.compile(template): Problem with lifecycle hooks if template string gets updated

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Hard to explain our whole project, but I try to break it down:

Vue2 v.2.7.10
Options API

For our customers we have a possibility to compile Vue template strings at runtime. In this context, its also possible to add and remove elements on the fly.

The responsible Vue component compiles our template. If changes happen, we pass the new template string and the compiler keeps track of changes behind and related components fire mounted and beforeDestroy hooks.

example:

```
templateStringOne: "<div><CustomComponent dummy-id='one'><CustomContainer dummy-id='c_one'/><CustomComponent dummy-id='two'></div>"

templateStringTwo: "<div><CustomComponent dummy-id='one'><CustomComponent dummy-id='two'></div>"
```

If the result gets logged, it shows inside beforeDestroy with dummy_id:"c_one".

But: If one of two CustomComponents side by side will be removed:

```
templateStringOne: "<div><CustomComponent dummy-id='one'><CustomComponent dummy-id='two'></div>"

templateStringTwo: "<div><CustomComponent dummy-id='two'></div>"
```

The results always will be dummy_id:"two" (the last dummy_id in place of [n] components) -> expecting dummy_id:"one". Despite of this attribute, if we log the _uuid of the VNode, it also shows the wrong id.

What happened ? Everything works like expected for about 2 years, but now we make use of the beforeDestroy lifecycle hook and the attributes not shown correctly.

A small reproducable example-project can be found here:
https://github.com/Splinti/vuejs-2-renderer-problem

Reproducable example as link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

The template compiler also needs the "key" property to refer to the correct instance. After modify, all lifecycle hooks work as expected.

Unfortunately, there is no warning like v-for directive use it if the key property was not provided.